# In E4 RCP application, how to add checkbox in the toolbar for part(in Application.e4xmi)

Tags: checkbox, toolbar, rcp, e4

[image: Application.e4xmi]

I have been trying to add the tool item with a checkbox for select/deselect all functionality. The handled tool item -> type in application.e4xmi is not helping as it always creates a button in the toolbar. I tried having a custom tool bar by masking the current tool bar implementation, but since the implementation has to be done in View/Part I couldn't find a better solution.

Please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The object created by 'Check' is not a button. It is a checkbox which draws as 'pressed' when it is checked, and 'unpressed' when it is not checked. That is the standard Eclipse way of drawing a tool bar check.

If you don't want that, add a Tool Control and create the check box control yourself in the handler for that code.